# How to prepare wrapper for ruby-2.6.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, rvm

I have a ubuntu 16 with rvm and some rubies install, default is 2.6.1

Also I have a directory `/usr/local/rvm/wrappers` with folders:

```
default  ruby-2.0.0-p481  ruby-2.0.0-p481@global  ruby-2.1.5  ruby-2.1.5@global
```

But working Ruby version is 2.6.1 - `which ruby` returns `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby`

Finally, I need to use crontab rows to schedule rails scripts, such way:

```
/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.6.1/rails sitemap:generate RAILS_ENV=production
```

How to create a ruby-2.6.1 folder into `/usr/local/rvm/wrappers`?

Comment: Here you can find more info about cron and wrappers: https://rvm.io/deployment/cron

Comment: Thanks, I found it at another path - /root/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.6.3, instead of above